# Adding i18next to nextJs API

Tags: next.js, i18next

I have nextJs application. For Internationalization I'm using [next-translate](https://github.com/vinissimus/next-translate). For the frontend part that works excellent. But also I have API built with nextjs (pages/api) and there I also want to support internationalization, for example, translate error messages:

```
...
 if (principal !== walletSigningfor)
    throw new Error(`Failed to login, signed message with different wallet....`)
...
```

Fined library [i18next-http-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18next-http-middleware) but not quite sure how to connect that to my nextjs Api and then how to connect that to next-translate. Is there any example of how I can achieve that?

Comment: i18next-http-middleware is a library used within the i18next ecosystem, not next-ranslate. For i18next, you should use next-i18next. A good tutorial can be found here: https://locize.com/blog/next-i18next/

Answer (score 0):

Do your translations have `.json` format? If yes, you can "import" the needed file with translations directly in the "backend" file. ([info](https://www.stefanjudis.com/snippets/how-to-import-json-files-in-es-modules-node-js/))

*But why do you need it?*

You can create your own status codes to return from the node and then translate it at "front-side".

```
{
...
//and get in FE message you need
errorCode: 88890;
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. I need to translate not only errors, there are multiple different things. Translation files are stored not in JSON files there stored in the database and editing through CMS.

Comment: You need to have this approach for only pages or also API routes?